# Rails/Redux/Devise - Trying to log in user but along the way the value of currentUser becomes HTML string of the document

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, redux, devise, react-redux

I'm working on a Rails/React/Redux app using Devise for user authentication. There's something fishy going on somewhere in between my login function and my receiveCurrentUser action where the currentUser becomes changed to an HTML string of the entire document. Here's what happens:

**I first dispatch this login function:**

```
export const login = (user) => (dispatch) => {
  debugger
  return SessionAPIUtil.login(user)
  .then(currentUser => {
    dispatch(receiveCurrentUser(currentUser));
    return currentUser;
  },
  errors => {
    dispatch(receiveSessionErrors(errors.responseJSON));
    return errors;
  });
};
```

Putting in a debugger I saw that my user was what it should be:

```
{username: "test_user", password: "password123"}
```

A debugger in my login util function (ajax call) still has user as what it should be.

```
export const login = user => {
  debugger
  return $.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/users/sign_in',
    data:  { user }
  });
};
```

However, when it returns from the ajax call to the ".then(..." of the first login function and we enter the receiveCurrentUser:

```
export const receiveCurrentUser = (currentUser) => {
  debugger
  return {
    type: RECEIVE_CURRENT_USER,
    currentUser
  };
};
```

a debugger reveals that currentUser is an HTML string of the document:

[image]

Any insight or advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This is probably because your sign in method returns the HTML doc as the response. Can you please check the network tab to check the response of your api call?

Comment: Just to preface that I'm not super well versed in checking the network tab in the console but here's what I found:

For the response under sign_in it says "Failed to load response data". However, for the response under localhost it's the HTML document.

Comment: First, make sure that your api works and returns data correctly. Go to chrome developer tools and network tab. This shows all requests/response going in and out of the browser for your site. Check response for the ajax call that is being made